# How to get label name by using string variable -c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to use a string variable to get a label name to change its text.
for example, I have the following code:

```
string labelName = "lbl_text";
lbl_Heart_Rate.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => lbl_Heart_Rate.Text = displayValue.ToString()));
```

How do I use the string variable labelName to change the lbl_text's value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find `Label` Control from the list of form control for a given name.

```
var control = this.Controls.OfType<Label>()
                           .FirstOrDefault(c=>c.Name == labelName");

if(control != null)
{
    // Now you can play with your logic.
    control.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => control.Text = displayValue.ToString())); 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the form has a function for this: [Control.ControlCollection.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Full Code:

```
string labelName = "lbl_text";
TextBox lbl_text = this.Controls.Find(labelName , true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
//You can access 'lbl_text' here...
```

Comment: And don't forget to check lbl_text for null.

Comment: This should be the correct answer, since Hari's answer does not considers that controls contain controls that contaşns controls (Composite pattern).