# finding a label name based on the text matching a variable

Tags: c#, winforms

in Visual studio in a C# winform I have a grid of 139 labels each with a unique text value displayed - how do I change the colour of one of those labels when a variable matches one of the label.text property, without knowing which label it is

for example I click on a datagrid row and it sets a variable to the code GG, how do I find which label in the grid has the text property = GG and then change the colour of that label only

the grid is in a tab control page so it must update on the correct tab page as well (the one active)

complete newbie trying to solve a problem

thanks in advance

Comment: Share some code

Comment: Ok, supposing, that you have a good reason to do as you did - you will simply meed to iterate the Controls collection of the form. With Linq it is a single-lune statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get label name by using string variable -c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368807/how-to-get-label-name-by-using-string-variable-c).  "label name" is the wrong way to think of it - you are probably after the object reference not the `.Name` property.  Never ignore the possible dupes the system offers when you type your title - there is a huge repository of ready to use solutions already here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose our 139 labels have text "label-xxx" where xxx is a number, and we are looking for "label-121" and want to make it red:

```
var c = this.Controls.FirstOrDefault(ctrl => ctrl is Label && ctrl.Text == "label-121");

if(c == null) {
  //put code here to handle the scenario where the label is not found
} else {
  c.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Note that the "this" refers to the form itself. If your labels are inside a panel, groupbox etc it would be necessary to enumerate the .Controls of that panel, not the form, because it's a hierarchy. If the labels are in multiple different panels please advise because you'd need a different way of looping through them

We don't actually need to cast our control to a label, because Text and BackColor properties are introduced into the inheritance hierarchy at Control level rather than the Label subclass. If you want to change other properties that are Label only then you'll have to cast `c` to a Label

I do think you'd be better off declaring a `Dictionary<string, Label>` though, and filling it with labels as they're put on the form (or filling it from the Controls collection) - if the label texts don't change this would be a cleaner way of tracking them

---

Getting Linq working is typically just adding a `using System.Linq;` at the top of the file with the rest of the code in. System.Linq is a member of the System.Core assembly. If your project lacks a reference to it then you may see errors about it being an unknown namespace

Here's a non-linq version of the code:

```
foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
{
  if(c is Label && c.Text == "label-121")
  {
    c.BackColor = Color.Red;
  }
}
```

Comment: hi, appreciate the feedback, as I mentioned I am a newbie so the <dictionary> is a new one on me that I would need to learn. for the Linq option I cant seem to be able to get it enabled, adding the system.linq doesn't seem to do anything and I found a reference to adding a public static class but again not sure where to reference this in the constructor. the code looks logical enough so long as I can reference the right control

Comment: I'll add a non linq version